# Why are Paperclip images coming up as missing.png?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I know there are a couple of questions about this out there on stackoverflow, but they either went right over my head or didn't seem relevant to my own question.

I am working on jumpstartlab's Blogger 2 project tutorial and have reached I4 after completing everything beforehand. The tutorial told us to install the paperclip gem, add:

```
class AddPaperclipFieldsToArticle < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :image_file_name, :string
    add_column :articles, :image_content_type, :string
    add_column :articles, :image_file_size, :integer
    add_column :articles, :image_updated_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

to the new migration database to add paperclip fields to article (and then rake this).

I then added this code:

```
has_attached_file :image
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]
```

to apps/models/article.rb, added :image to app/helpers/articles_helper.rb

Here is my _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@article, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
<ul>
    <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
    <li><%= error %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :image, "Attach an Image" %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :tag_list %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Why is the image I add always changing to missing.png? I have tried with multiple images, changed Paperclip to an older version, but the output has always been the same.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

View code for show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>

<p><%= image_tag(@article.image.url) %></p>

<p><%= @article.body %></p>

<h3>Comments (<%= @article.comments.size %>)</h3>

<%= render partial: 'articles/comment', collection: @article.comments %>
<%= render partial: 'comments/form' %>

<%= link_to "<< Back to Articles' List", articles_path %>

<%= link_to "delete", article_path(@article), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete the article?"} %>

<%= link_to "edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>

<p>
    Tags:
    <% @article.tags.each do |tag| %>
    <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag) %>
    <% end %>
</p>
```

articles_controller code

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
include ArticlesHelper
def index
    @articles = Article.all
end
def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment.article_id = @article.id
end
def new
    @article = Article.new
end
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save

    flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Created!"

    redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Deleted!"

    redirect_to action: 'index'
end
def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.update(article_params)

    flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Updated!"

    redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
end
```

Comment: Is the Article record updated with the data relating to the image?  If so, what is the full path to the file?  Is there a file at that location?  Just start from the basics like this and you should be able to work out whether the file has been saved and if there is just some issue with the link to the file, or if it hasn't been saved at all.

Comment: Could you please add your view code and the related controller action to the question?

Comment: Sorry @TheFabio I've added it now.

Comment: @MaxWilliams do you mean things like the default url, url and path? I'm pretty new to Rails but did a bit of research and I guess you save files using these?

Comment: could you please confirm if your table record gets created and the image file is store where it should

Comment: To be safe, could you post your `def article_params` method in the controller? It should be there in order to apply the Strong Parameters feature of Rails 4 ... and you're calling it from the update and create methods :)! I'm curious to see that the right params are allowed in order to save the image/attachment during the save/update.

Answer (score 2):

```
Why are Paperclip images coming up as missing.png?
```

This literally describes the problem. When Article's `:image` is `nil`, no matter what you try, it will show this default `missing.png` because this case is handled by `Paperclip` itself.

However, you can use [default_url](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.3.8/Paperclip/ClassMethods%3Ahas_attached_file) option to set a custom default image when the article's image is missing.

Alternatively, you can use a conditional like this:

```
if @article.image_file_name.present?
  # this makes sure the article has an image
  # show the article image
else
  # show the custom default image here
end
```

#### Update

Basically, your image uploading is not working. Make sure you have this in your controller:

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:image)
end
```

I suspect, there are some validation error when you create your article. To make sure, change your `create` method to this:

```
def create
    @article = Article.create!(article_params)

    flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Created!"

    redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

Using `create!` instead of `new` will throw an exception if there is any error while creating the article and you will be able to know the exact problem.

Try this and let me know! If you get any error when using `create!` while creating the article, update your question with those information. I am almost certain that you will get an image content type validation error. If that's the case, then we will add a custom validation for your image and content_type and make sure it works. But, we will see!